# How to include namespace in the msbuild project file

Tags: msbuild

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="FluentMigrator, Version=1.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aacfc7de5acabf05, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.1\lib\40\FluentMigrator.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="FluentExtensions.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target
    Name="Build2"
    Inputs="@(Compile)"
    Outputs="HelloWorld.dll"
  >
    <Csc
      OutputAssembly="HelloWorld.dll"
      Sources="@(Compile)"
      TargetType="library"
    />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

Hello, why is the "Build" target works fine but "Build2" says "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FluentMigrator' could not be found"? What should I include in the proj? I tried to include the system libs like System, System.Core, but no effect.

Comment: Try updating Csc task to include `References="@(Reference)"`

Comment: @sthotakura Error: Can not found metadata file "FluentMigrator, Version=1.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aacfc7de5acabf05, processorArchitecture=MSIL".

Comment: Replace reference to `<Reference Include="..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.1\lib\40\FluentMigrator.dll" />` and it works fine. Thank you for `References="@(Reference)"`